# Sequelize associations methods is not working

Tags: node.js, database, sequelize.js, mysql2

I'm using nodejs trying to connect two tables in database using musql2 and sequelize npm module.
I have two tables text and category. text is the child of category when im using sequelize methods category.getText() it is returning an error "createtext is not a function.

this is the model of text

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize)
const sequelize = require('../database/sequelize')

const Text = sequelize.define('Text', {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
    },
    anyText: {
        type: Sequelize.TEXT,
        allowNull: false,
    },
    state: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
    },


})

module.exports = Text;
```

the model of category

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize)

const sequelize = require('../database/sequelize')

const Category = sequelize.define('category', {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
    },
    category: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
    },
})

module.exports = Category;
```

the code I'm trying to run

```
const sequelize = require('./database/sequelize')

const Text = require('./models/text')
const Category = require('./models/category')

Category.getTexts()
.then( text => {
   console.log(text)
})
.catch(err => {
   console.log(err)
})


Text.belongsTo(Category, { constraints: true, onDelete: 'CASCADE'});
Category.hasMany(Text),

//{ force: true}
sequelize
  .sync()
  // .sync({ force: true})
  .then(result => {
    console.log('connected');
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

the error is

```
Category.getTexts()
         ^

TypeError: Category.getTexts is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\karim\Desktop\ex\exp.js:6:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:829:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
```

Comment: Did you solve that Karim?

Answer (score 0):

try to write associations in their related models:
take this line to Text model file

```
Text.belongsTo(Category, { constraints: true, onDelete: 'CASCADE'});
```

and this one to Category model

```
Category.hasMany(Text),
```

Answer (score 0):

Root of the issue comes with the pluralization of methods as sequelize will do it's own modification about it.
So, model definition is already singular.

```
const Text = sequelize.define('Text', {
id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    autoIncrement: true,
    allowNull: false,
    primaryKey: true,
},
anyText: {
    type: Sequelize.TEXT,
    allowNull: false,
},
state: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
},
```

Then on the function call you should also do it as singular like:

```
    Category.getText() //text instead of texts
    .then( text => {
   console.log(text)
})
.catch(err => {
   console.log(err)
})
```

That worked for me, hope it helps future generations..

Answer (score -1):

**First of all you have change your text model like this addcategory relation in side the model.**

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize)
const sequelize = require('../database/sequelize')
const Category = require('./category.model');

const Text = sequelize.define('Text', {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
    },
    anyText: {
        type: Sequelize.TEXT,
        allowNull: false,
    },
    state: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
    },
})

Text.belongsTo(Category, { constraints: true, onDelete: 'CASCADE'});
Category.hasMany(Text),

module.exports = Text;
```

**After that you have to change your running code with this.**

```
const sequelize = require('./database/sequelize')

const Text = require('./models/text')
const Category = require('./models/category')

sequelize.sync().then(result => { 
    console.log('connected'); 
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err); 
});

model.Category.findAll({
    where:{ your condition },
    include :[
        {
            model : model.Text,
            attributes : [ text field name], // If want to get all the field simple delete this line            
            required:true, // If you want to find all the category which has text then pass true else false
        },
    ]    
})
.then(PostData => {            
    if(PostData.count > 0){
        console.log("Post Data===>",PostData)
    }
    else{
        console.log("Post Data===> No record found")
    }
}).catch(err => {
    console.log("Post Data===> No record found")
})
```